# Jena OWL/RDF FunctionalProperty

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

I need to achieve such OWL format:

```
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="Role-description"> <rdfs:range
rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Role"/>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
```

I am using Jena and when I try to do next:

```
DatatypeProperty datatypeProperty = ontModel.createDatatypeProperty(OWL.NS + "Role-description");
datatypeProperty.addRDFType(OWL.FunctionalProperty);
datatypeProperty.asDatatypeProperty();
```

Get all vise a versa.

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Task"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Actor"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Task-performedBy-Actor"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Actor-performs-Task"/>
  <owl:FunctionalProperty rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Role-description">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty"/>
  </owl:FunctionalProperty>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Will appreciate any advice

Comment: I don't understand wh yit's important how the data is serialized. The semantics is supposed to be the same and any proper parser will get the same complete and correct information out of it. There is no ordering in the serialization of OWL since  an OWL ontology consist of a set of OWL axioms

Comment: @AKSW I've seen similar 'needs' frequently, often as a result of overly specified requests or assignments. Often the result of interaction with non-RDF or non-OWL toolchains as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are getting is not *vice versa*. What you basically have is an RDF resource with multiple types. It's up to Jena how to serialise them (i.e. which one to consider "primary"). To illustrate, I will serialise your example to Turtle (slightly modified to use custom namespace):

```
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix roles: <http://example.com/ns/roles#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

roles:Role-description
        a       owl:DatatypeProperty , owl:FunctionalProperty .
```

Now, here is how you can *manipulate* the order of the types for a convenient serialisation:

```
public static final String ROLES_NS = "http://example.com/ns/roles#";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
    ontModel.setNsPrefix("roles", ROLES_NS);

    DatatypeProperty prop = ontModel.createDatatypeProperty(
            ROLES_NS + "Role-description");
    prop.setRDFType(OWL.FunctionalProperty);
    prop.addRDFType(OWL.DatatypeProperty);

    RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, ontModel, RDFFormat.RDFXML_PRETTY);
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:roles="http://example.com/ns/roles#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://example.com/ns/roles#Role-description">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
</rdf:RDF>
```